# c# webbrowser click radio button in a form

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am using webbrowser element in my code to automate some stuff. I am loading a form in this webbrowser, which contains several radiobutton in. My purpose is just to select one of the radi buttons. However, in the html code, there is a JS code which changes the form action target depending on the selected radio button. So if I use,

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chicken").SetAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

it selects the radio button that I want but just that. I mean it doesn't trigger the JS code. In this JS Code, it also submits the page, so my code above only selects the radio button and calls the same page. How can I solve this?

Form tag is like the following:

```
<form id="choose_dept" method="POST" action="/place/">
```

JS code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$("#choose_dept").change(function(){
  $("#choose_dept").attr('action', '/place/' + ('input[name=department]:checked').val()
   + '/' );
  this.submit();
});
```

-->

Last edit:

```
        String sc = @"$(document).ready(function(){" +
        "$(\"input:radio[name=department]\").change(function() {" +
        "$(\"#choose_dept\").attr('action','place/'+$(this).val());" +
        "$(\"#choose_dept\").submit();" +
        "});" +
        "});";

        HtmlElement headElem = (HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptElem = (HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement elem = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElem.DomElement;
        elem.text = sc;
        headElem.AppendChild(scriptElem);

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chicken").SetAttribute("checked", "checked");
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ready()");
```

Comment: Did you try putting this inside a DocumentCompleted event? And what should be the event that would trigger your javascript, onclick or onload etc?

Comment: Hi Thirdy,
I wrote this call in a button event. So it's already loaded when I click the button.

Comment: Ok, how about the javascript, what event that should trigger it?

Comment: I have edited my first post for more info.

Form tag is like the following:
<form id="choose_dept" method="POST"
      action="/place/">

JS code is like this:
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--


$("#choose_dept").change(function(){

  $("#choose_dept").attr('action',
       '/place/' + $('input[name=department]:checked').val()
       + '/' );

  this.submit();
});
      -->
  </script>

Comment: Looks like you're using jquery. In your example you're using chicken as your id element in your GetElementByid instead of choose_dept. is that intentional?

Comment: But one of them is from form id, the other one is from radiobutton id. Script says that if anything changes in "choose_dept", which is a form, than change the attribute of the action as described. The purpose is how to trigger form change event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case more than c# code your problem is your jquery code. Try the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio[name=department]").change(function() {
$("#choose_dept").attr('action','place/'+$(this).val());
$("#choose_dept").submit();
});
});
```

**Edit**: (Since you mentioned that you have no control with the HTML code then you could just add on the fly the JavaScript that I just showed you with the code like the one below:

```
        String sc = @"$(document).ready(function(){
               $("input:radio[name=department]").change(function() {
               $("#choose_dept").attr('action','place/'+$(this).val());
               $("#choose_dept").submit();
               });
               });";

        var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        var headElem = (HtmlElement) doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var scriptElem = (HtmlElement) doc.CreateElement("script");
        var elem = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElem.DomElement;
        elem.text = sc;
        headElem.AppendChild(scriptElem);
```

However, you need to add Reference

```
 Microsoft.mshtml
```

The you need to add also at the top of your code

```
 using mshtml;
```

Now, if you don't want to change it on the fly and you really want just to call the javascript method then you could use the one below:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("methodnamehere()");
```

**Latest Edit based on your code:**

I think you need to simulate a click in your browser once you check your radio button.
So, it would be like this now:

```
 String sc = @"$(document).ready(function(){" +
        "$(\"input:radio[name=department]\").change(function() {" +
        "$(\"#choose_dept\").attr('action','place/'+$(this).val());" +
        "$(\"#choose_dept\").submit();" +
        "});" +
        "});";

        HtmlElement headElem = (HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptElem = (HtmlElement)webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
        IHTMLScriptElement elem = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElem.DomElement;
        elem.text = sc;
        headElem.AppendChild(scriptElem);

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chicken").SetAttribute("checked", "checked");

        HtmlElement simulateClick = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chicken");
        simulateClick.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: That's good but the html code that I load into webbrowser is not my code. I can't change it.

Comment: Hi Thirdy,

Could you please check my edit in my first post? I have already tried what you said but still no luck. The thing is, when I debug the code, webbrowser1 doesn't contain the script but the headElem parameter although it seems that webbrowser1 is set for this. I really couldn't get it.

Comment: @Dundar Check again my edit. I edited your posted code by adding a simulation for Clicking your radio button in your web browser. It should work because I really tested it on my own PC. GOD bless.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chicken").RaiseEvent("onchange");
```

Comment: That was a good hint but unfortunately it didn't help. Doesn't trigger anything. Is there any way to call the JQery function directly?